# Luggage locker at Warsaw Central Railway Station

Tags: trains, luggage-storage, warsaw

I am wondering if there are luggage lockers at Warsaw central railway station (I highly suspect there are) and if there are, do they have different size lockers? and I'd like to know the prices. Couldn't find exact information via google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Man in Seat 61 says that there is both an unmanned 24-hour locker service, as well as a manned left-luggage service at Warsaw Central station. [Quoting from the Man himself](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_offices_&_lockers_in_other_European_cities):

> **Warsaw**:  Warsaw Centralna has luggage lockers in the passageway at the top of the steps to the platforms, around 9 zlotys (£2) per locker per 24 hours.  There's a staffed left luggage office off the same passageway, 10 zlotys per item per 24 hours, open 07:00-18:20, 19:00-06:20 with breaks 10:00-10:15 & 14:00-14:30.

Answer (score 2):

Various sizes at 12,14,16 Złoty for 24 hours, as at Feb 2019. Medium rucksack to large enough for 2 decent size suitcases.

Answer (score 0):

There are, unmanaged ones can be found at the North-East corner, don't remember exactly but most likely at (-1) level. As far as I remember there are quite spacious lockers.